# Issue with transform XSLT to XML

Tags: xml, xslt

```
XSLT 1.0
```

Here is input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <id_brand>45</id_brand>
        <brand_name><![CDATA[DIESEL]]></brand_name>
        <attributes><![CDATA[Wodoodporność: 3 ATM - Średnica: 62 mm - Rodzaj: Męskie - Materiał: Stal nierdzewna - Materiał paska: Skóra - Mechanizm: Kwarcowy - Funkcje: Wielofunkcyjność - Szkiełko: Mineralne - Rodzaj produktu: Zegarek na rękę - Opakowanie: Oficjalne pudełko]]></attributes>
    </product>
</products>
```

From this XML I need get only content from tag `attributes`. Im 100% sure everything is OK with create tags from this description. Only is issues with tags `<products>` and `<product>` in XSLT template.

I use below XSLT template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <product>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(attributes)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </product>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' - '"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <xsl:element name="{translate(substring-before($token, ': '), ' ', '_')}">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($token, ': ')" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But something went wrong.

I try from above code to get result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
<product>
  <Wodoodporność>3 ATM</Wodoodporność>
  <Średnica>62 mm</Średnica>
  <Rodzaj>Męskie</Rodzaj>
  <Materiał>Stal nierdzewna</Materiał>
  <Materiał_paska>Skóra</Materiał_paska>
  <Mechanizm>Kwarcowy</Mechanizm>
  <Funkcje>Wielofunkcyjność</Funkcje>
  <Szkiełko>Mineralne</Szkiełko>
  <Rodzaj_produktu>Zegarek na rękę</Rodzaj_produktu>
  <Opakowanie>Oficjalne pudełko</Opakowanie>
</product>
</products>
```

update:
@michael.hor257k you have right.  But see what happens. When `<products><product>...</product><product>...</product> </products>` occurs twice or more.

Everytime I get only result:

```
<product>
   <Wodoodporność>3 ATM</Wodoodporność>
   <Średnica>62 mm</Średnica>
   <Rodzaj>Męskie</Rodzaj>
   <Materiał>Stal nierdzewna</Materiał>
   <Materiał_paska>Skóra</Materiał_paska>
   <Mechanizm>Kwarcowy</Mechanizm>
   <Funkcje>Wielofunkcyjność</Funkcje>
   <Szkiełko>Mineralne</Szkiełko>
   <Rodzaj_produktu>Zegarek na rękę</Rodzaj_produktu>
   <Opakowanie>Oficjalne pudełko</Opakowanie>
</product>
```

This above result is from input:
[image]

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Please do not edit OP's code.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I didn't touch the OP XSLT code, just formatted input XML.

Comment: The input XML **is** code.

Comment: @TomArm Please post code as code, not as pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But something went wrong.

That "something" is *context*. You are in the context of `products` - but `attributes` is a child of `product` - therefore your instruction:

```
<xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(attributes)"/>
```

selects nothing. Change it to:

```
<xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(product/attributes)"/>
```

---

***--- added ---***

If you have multiple `product` elements, then you *probably* want to do:

```
<xsl:template match="/products">
    <products>
        <xsl:for-each select="product">
            <product>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(attributes)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </product>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </products>
</xsl:template>
```

It's hard to be sure without an example showing a representative  input (as code) and the expected output.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: once again thank you for your help. It's almost working. I have one question. You see in our output date: <brand_name><![CDATA[DIESEL]]></brand_name>. I try get this in XSLT via <xsl:element name="brand_name">
  <xsl:value-of select="brand_name"/>
</xsl:element>. But display only </reference> Can you please check this last thing?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the current question. Please post it separately and make sure to include a [mcve] incl. input, your XSLT and the expected output - all as code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68126555/how-to-get-extra-parametr-during-convers-xsllt