# How to get extra parametr during convers xsllt

Tags: xml, xslt

Below I paste output date our original XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <reference><![CDATA[DZT1000]]></reference>
        <attributes><![CDATA[Wodoodpornosc: 3 ATM - Srednica: 62 mm - Rodzaj: Meskie - Material: Stal nierdzewna - Material paska: Skora - Mechanizm: Kwarcowy - Funkcje: Wielofunkcyjnosc - Szkielko: Mineralne - Rodzaj produktu: Zegarek na reke - Opakowanie: Oficjalne pudelko]]></attributes>
    </product>
    <product>
        <reference><![CDATA[DZT10002]]></reference>
        <attributes><![CDATA[Wodoodpornosc: 3 ATM - Srednica: 62 mm - Rodzaj: Meskie - Material: Stal nierdzewna - Material paska: Skora - Mechanizm: Kwarcowy - Funkcje: Wielofunkcyjnosc - Szkielko: Mineralne - Rodzaj produktu: Zegarek na reke - Opakowanie: Oficjalne pudelko]]></attributes>
    </product>
</products>
```

We use XSLT 1.0 Template, below is ready code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <products>
        <xsl:for-each select="product">
            <product>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(attributes)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </product>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </products>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' - '"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <xsl:element name="{translate(substring-before($token, ': '), ' ', '_')}">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($token, ': ')" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Currently I get Result from above:

```
<products>
   <product>
      <Wodoodpornosc>3 ATM</Wodoodpornosc>
      <Srednica>62 mm</Srednica>
      <Rodzaj>Meskie</Rodzaj>
      <Material>Stal nierdzewna</Material>
      <Material_paska>Skora</Material_paska>
      <Mechanizm>Kwarcowy</Mechanizm>
      <Funkcje>Wielofunkcyjnosc</Funkcje>
      <Szkielko>Mineralne</Szkielko>
      <Rodzaj_produktu>Zegarek na reke</Rodzaj_produktu>
      <Opakowanie>Oficjalne pudelko</Opakowanie>
   </product>
   <product>
      <Wodoodpornosc>3 ATM</Wodoodpornosc>
      <Srednica>62 mm</Srednica>
      <Rodzaj>Meskie</Rodzaj>
      <Material>Stal nierdzewna</Material>
      <Material_paska>Skora</Material_paska>
      <Mechanizm>Kwarcowy</Mechanizm>
      <Funkcje>Wielofunkcyjnosc</Funkcje>
      <Szkielko>Mineralne</Szkielko>
      <Rodzaj_produktu>Zegarek na reke</Rodzaj_produktu>
      <Opakowanie>Oficjalne pudelko</Opakowanie>
   </product>
</products>
```

Output date contain extra attribute: `<reference><![CDATA[DZT1000]]></reference>`

How can I get this attribute in XSLT?

I tried to use value select etc but unfortunately I can't get this attribute in any way. Please note that the original file contains many other attributes but we just want to download the addend to this `<reference>` can anyone help us?

Comment: I don't understand why you say "Output date contain extra attribute: `<reference><![CDATA[DZT1000]]></reference>`", it seems that is part of the input data. So in what way do you want to process that element, which result do you want in the output for it? Just copy it?

Comment: I think we've got a difficulty with English here (and with incorrect use of technical terms): I think he's trying to say "I want the output data to contain an extra element".

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you only need to do:

```
<xsl:template match="/products">
    <products>
        <xsl:for-each select="product">
            <product>
                <xsl:copy-of select="reference"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(attributes)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </product>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </products>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Note that `reference` in the input XML is an **element** - not a **parameter** nor an **attribute**.